# Can you code on an iPad?

Tags: apex, code, ipad

I've been thinking of buying an iPad and I was wondering if I could write my apex classes on an iPad? My iPhone's browser redirected me to the Salesforce1 app after I tried logging in to my sandbox. Could someone please clarify this?

Comment: For what it's worth, I do most of my Salesforce development on a $130 Chromebook running Linux. I think "low power" is an easier trade-off to make than "tablet".

Comment: IDE's run on chromebooks?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Sure, if you wipe its brain and install GalliumOS (Ubuntu offshoot).

Comment: @PranayJaiswal We're in the Cloud era. There are a ton of IDEs that run directly in one's browser, some paid, some free. If you need to code, like "right now," it can be done. I personally use aside.io for quick edits, I used to love Cloud9 but it was taken over by Amazon and, IMHO, sucks now.

Comment: Is there something you want from the iPad in particular? Or is it that you want to go to something more lightweight for your day-to-day, like a tablet?

Comment: @pchittum, I'm planning to buy an iPad and was wondering if, in case of an emergency, I do not have my laptop with me, will I be able to code or deploy change sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [aside.io](https://aside.io/) (this is just one I'm familiar with, feel free to find your own), or other online cloud IDE services for Salesforce to do development with. You can try the Developer Console, but in my experience, it doesn't work well on mobile devices (graphically glitchy, touch controls are pretty bad). To do this, before logging in (at login screen), use your browser's "Request Desktop Site" feature (Chrome and Safari have different ways to do this). Once in Desktop mode, you can use the Developer Console. It's better than *nothing*, but I wouldn't want to do long-term development on a mobile device.

Comment: classic class/vf edit works well in iPhone.  I kinda use it when am outta office and suddenly remember to add some checks in Apex code.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal It also has like, absolutely no features, like proper autocompletion and other cool IDE features, and I don't think there's any Lightning support, either. But I have from time to time found a use for this editor. Like when you get that mid-travel inspiration and your laptop just isn't feasible.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a native Ios iPad answer, but let me give my lil hack to it.

Coding on iPad / Tabs/ Android might seem a good idea for a short amount of time, but in long run, it will just frustrate you. Salesforce development is not just about writing code, its more about using process builder, use of Data loaders, complex IDE that help you change tidbits that SF ui doesn't allow, and use of Version Control softwares, CI CD jobs etc will require something more than an iPad and a browser. It will require a desktop.

Ipad allows you to Remote Desktop into any windows /mac. I use that feature to Rdp into my amazon Windows 10 [machine](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/amazon-workspaces-introduces-windows-10-desktop-experience/), its my primary workspace which i can access from anywhere on my lil tab and code like a desktop on it by attaching mouse and keyboard, its couple of quid every month which is worth it.

If you want a high performance machine, not just for SF coding but for coding heavy Java/C++ etc stuffs or even gaming you can use [Shadow PC](https://www.cultofmac.com/567661/blade-shadow-windows-10-iphone-ipad/) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just get a Windows MINI PC, and then run a Remote Software like teamviewer, keep the mini pc to run allways ON, whenever you want to code from IPAD or mobile device just connect remote and work on it :-D problem solved, you get the both . haha